# Conditional file listing on gridView in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-io

I am writing a file management web page for a friend of mine. I select the folder using a DropDownlist element. When the index changed it populates gridview.

For preventing user slips, I have decided not to delete the file when <kbd>Delete</kbd> button is clicked. I change the name of the deleted file adding a suffix.

For example if I delete a `file.pdf` via <kbd>Delete</kbd>button, it is renamed as `file.pdf_zkanoca_deleted_1411472294`

After populating the gridview content, renamed files are still listed. My `listFiles()` method is as the following:

```
public void listFiles(string selectedFolder)
{
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(selectedFolder);

    gridView1.DataSource = dir.GetFiles();
    gridView1.DataBind();
}
```

What I want is to check whether filename contains "`_zkanoca_deleted_`" string before binding data source to gridview. If it contains that string it will not be listed.

I think a `foreach` loop will solve my problem. But I could not imagine how to structure it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [IEnumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) extension

```
gridView1.DataSource = dir.GetFiles().Where(x => !x.Name.Contains("_zkanoca_deleted_")).ToList();
```

As explained in the docs the Where extension filters a sequence using a predicate.
In this case you could use the FileInfo property Name to check if it contains the forbidden substring and exclude that FileInfo from the sequence binded to the gridview.

Comment: why double quotes are like that? `""_zkanoca_deleted_" "`

Comment: your suggestion looks pretty good and agile but `gridView1.DataSource = dir.GetFiles().Where(x => !x.Name.Contains(""_zkanoca_deleted_" ")).ToList();` gives error and after removing (I guess) unnecessary double quotes `gridView1.DataSource = dir.GetFiles().Where(x => !x.Name.Contains("_zkanoca_deleted_")).ToList();` it does not hide deleted files.

Comment: Sorry copy/paste error. You are right to remove them

Comment: This version of Contains is case sensitive. If the forbidden text is not all in lowercase then Contains return false and the file will be listed.

Comment: My bad, I have written something else instead of _zkanoca_deleted_ in my local language.